# Rewrite rule conversion help - Apache to Nginx

Tags: nginx, rewrite

Looking to convert the follow Apache rewrite rules over to Nginx. We are trying to get this to work on a subdirectory but can't seem to get the syntax down correctly.

```
RewriteRule ^([^//]+)/?(.{2})?/$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^([^//]+)/?(.*)?/index([0-9]*).ht(m?ml?)$ index.php?page=$1&rlVareables=$2&pg=$3 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^([^/][\w\-\_]+)(.+)-l?([0-9]+).ht(m|ml)$ index.php?page=$1&rlVareables=$2&listing_id=$3 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^((\w{2})/)?([\w-_]{3,})$ index.php?page=$3&lang=$2&account_request [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^([^//]+)/?(^/*)?.ht(m?ml?)$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^([^//]+)/?(.*)?/?(.*)?(.ht(m?ml?)|/+)$ index.php?page=$1&rlVareables=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
location /something {
  rewrite "^/([^//]+)/?(.{2})?/$" /index.php?page=$1 break;
  rewrite ^/([^//]+)/?(.*)?/index([0-9]*).ht(m?ml?)$ /index.php?page=$1&rlVareables=$2&pg=$3 break;
  rewrite ^/([^/][\w\-\_]+)(.+)-l?([0-9]+).ht(m|ml)$ /index.php?page=$1&rlVareables=$2&listing_id=$3 break;
  rewrite "^/((\w{2})/)?([\w-_]{3,})$" /index.php?page=$3&lang=$2&account_request break;
  rewrite ^/([^//]+)/?(^/*)?.ht(m?ml?)$ /index.php?page=$1 break;
  rewrite ^/([^//]+)/?(.*)?/?(.*)?(.ht(m?ml?)|/+)$ /index.php?page=$1&rlVareables=$2 break;
}
```